# How to configure Spring for using TransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm trying to understand how  to use Spring `DataSourceTransactionManager`.

I'm trying to follow this [example](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-jpa-hibernate-example).
But, when I start Tomcat from Eclipse, I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:159)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:106)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:227)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:623)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
```

This is the relevant code of DispatcherServlet.xml

```
   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">          
             <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
         </bean>    

        <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <tx:attributes>
                <tx:method name="create" />
            </tx:attributes>
        </tx:advice>

        <aop:config>
            <aop:pointcut id="userDaoTxPointcut" expression="execution(* com.springgestioneerrori.DAO.UtenteDAO.salvaUtente(..))" />
            <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userDaoTxPointcut" />
        </aop:config>
```

salvaUtente() is the method where I'll handle multiple `inserts` (now is still exmpty).

Comment: If it is annotated with `@Transactional` then why on earth do you have xml based tx configuration? Remove the `tx:advice` and `aop:config` and add `tx:annotation-driven` instead. The error has to do with a missing dependency on your classpath (probably aspectjrt.jar or aspectjweaver.jar)

Comment: Sorry, I was editing another post and I forgot to delete that sentence, I have not annotation actually.
Anyway, i added aspectj-1.6.9 to my classpath and I get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A jar is missing in your classpath:

```xml
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectjweaver.version}</version>    
</dependency>
```

Comment: I added aspectj-1.6.9 to my classpath and I get the same error

Comment: @MatteoDepasquali You need aspectj**weaver**. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11446893/1225328.