# Understanding AspectJ style with Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop

I'm reading [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj) about AOP and now I'm at the section about using `@AspectJ` style.

> ***Spring AOP is implemented in pure Java. There is no need for a special***
>   ***compilation process***. Spring AOP does not need to control the class
>   loader hierarchy, and is thus suitable for use in a Servlet container
>   or application server.

But in the section about `@AspectJ` style said

> The `@AspectJ` support can be enabled with XML or Java style
>   configuration. In either case you will also need to ensure that
>   AspectJ’s `aspectjweaver.jar` library is on the classpath of your
>   application (version 1.6.8 or later).

As far as I know, `aspectjweaver.jar` performs the actual weaving of aspects at compile-time or load time. But Spring has its own proxy-based implementation. So I really don't see any reason for `aspectjweaver.jar` dependency.

That's true, to use `@Aspect` annotation we need `aspectjrt` dependency. But the dependency on weaver is not clear to me. Couldn't you explain in a nutshell how it actually works?

Comment: Some related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11446893/spring-aop-why-do-i-need-aspectjweaver

Comment: That jar is needed as it contains classes which enable spring to parse the expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AOP doesn't use the AspectJ weaver itself, but it reuses some of the classes from the `aspectjweaver.jar` file. It is used to define AspectJ-style pointcut expression, e.g. `@Before`.